# How to split a File Source into Strings or Words

Tags: file, scala, split

I have a file with content like this:

```
"Some","Words","separated","by","comma","and","quoted","with","double","quotes"
```

The File is to large to read it into just on String.

What is the simplest way to split it into a Traversable of Strings, with each element being a word?

If it matters: While the content of the file won't fit in a single String the resulting Traversable might be a List without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of your own solution, using [`JavaConversions`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions%24) to manipulate the Java iterator as a Scala one.

```
import java.util.Scanner
import java.io.File
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val scanner = new Scanner(new File("...")).useDelimiter(",")
scanner.map(_.trim).map(quoted => quoted.substring(1, quoted.length - 1))
```

This gives you an iterator. You can always convert it to a list using e.g. `.toList`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using `stringLit` and `repsep` from Scala parser combinators. I won't vouch for its efficiency, though.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical.StdTokenParsers
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.StdLexical
import scala.util.parsing.input.StreamReader

import java.io.FileReader

object P extends StdTokenParsers {
  type Tokens = StdLexical

  val lexical = new StdLexical
  lexical.delimiters += ","

  def words : Parser[List[String]] = repsep(stringLit, ",")

  def getWords(fileName : String) : List[String] = {
    val scanner = new lexical.Scanner(StreamReader(new FileReader(fileName)))
    // better error handling wouldn't hurt.
    words(scanner).get
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not to concerned about performance. What bothers me more is that it is rather wordy.

Comment: @JensSchauder The `stringLit` parse takes care of the quotes properly.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using the java.util.Scanner while it does work, I'd appreciate a more scalaesc version.

```
val scanner = new Scanner(new File("""bigFile.txt""")).useDelimiter(",")
var wordList: Vector[String] = Vector()
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  val quoted = scanner.next()
  val word = quoted.replace("\"", "")
  wordList = wordList :+ word
}
```